# Laravel joining tables in a database query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have this code:

```
$classic_games_money = DB::table('bets')
    ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)
    ->sum('price');
```

It displays the amount of income, but i need to display this information only if the user id indicated in the `winner_id` column in `games` table. That is, how can I connect another table in this query?

Comment: You need to provide more detail here. What are the relationships between `Game`, `User`, and `Bet` models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `join` here, `exists` will be enough. I guess you have `game_id` column in `bets` table.

```
$classic_games_money = DB::table('bets')
    ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)
    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query
            ->selectRaw(1)
            ->from('games')
            ->whereRaw('games.id = bets.game_id')
            ->whereRaw('games.winner_id = bets.user_id');
    })
    ->sum('price');
```

Comment: yes, all work good. but can you discribe me, what `->selectRaw(1)` means?

Comment: It means something like this: we don't need to select any column to exists function, we have 1 and this is enough for exists to unserstand that we have row.

Comment: sorry for my impudence, but can you answer another question? it is related to the same issue, but there is a slightly different solution. I will be grateful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60361688/laravel-joining-tables-in-a-database-query-with-bind-values-question