# Laravel joining tables in a database query with bind values question

Tags: php, laravel

I have a earnings column on my site, I need to display the entire amount of earnings using a query in the database, but there is a small problem.

The table `bets_double` has columns: `game_id`, `sum`, `color`, and `userid`. And in the table `game_double` I have a column `number` it means winning number and `id`. In controller i bind numbers to colors this way:

```
$red = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
$black = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
$zero = [0];
```

How can I make a request in Laravel so that from the table `bets_double` take value `color` and checked the value from the table `game_double` and the total amount of victories was displayed?

For example, if in `bets_double` write `color` red, and in `game_double` number from 1 to 7 as write in `$red` variable, then to display the total winning. How to do it?

An example request code, but I don’t know how to send the values of variables in this code:

```
    $double_games_money = DB::table('bets_double')
    ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)
    ->whereExists(function ($query) {
        $query
            ->selectRaw(1)
            ->from('game_double')
            ->whereRaw('game_double.id = bets_double.game_id')
            ->whereRaw('game_double.number = bets_double.color');
    })
```

Comment: so you have an array of numbers set for each color in PHP, and then in DB you have color in one table, and numbers in another?

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: and why wouldn't you add another column in game_double for color, or create a pivot table for a color-number combination?

Comment: > and why wouldn't you add another column in game_double for color?
if i add it, i think it not decide my problem

> create a pivot table for a color-number combination?
can you describe? i first hear about it